# Why are my closing brackets being displayed on my webpage after using an echo?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to attach log out and save edits buttons to my website using this piece of code:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION[userId])){

        echo'<form action="hidden/logout.hid.php" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Log out</button>
            </form>  
            <button type="submit" name="editsave" onclick="saveEdits()">Save Edits</button>';
    }
?>
```

For some reason the `" ';}?>` is being displayed on my website, as in the image. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Website display]

Comment: Can you post the full code - I don't think there's anything wrong with what you've posted.

Comment: Try to change  `if (isset($_SESSION[userId])){` to   `if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])){` ..

Comment: My guess is that you're not running it in a PHP file, or PHP is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

The php statements starts and ends with brackets .

```
<?php ... ?>
```

Before the html tags the end bracket of PHP needs to be added.

try the below code snippet

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION[userId])){

    echo'?><form action="hidden/logout.hid.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Log out</button>
        </form>  
        <button type="submit" name="editsave" onclick="saveEdits()">Save 
     Edits</button><?php';
    }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this in a *.php file:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["userId"])): ?>
  <form action="hidden/logout.hid.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Log out</button>
  </form>  
  <button type="submit" name="editsave" onclick="saveEdits()">Save Edits</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Whats the output of

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```